# starting, stoping web application from MBean with JBoss AS 7.2.0

Tags: jboss7.x, mbeans

I'd like to check status and start/stop deployments of a web app programatically in JBoss as 7.2.0Final.
I've found that for status it can be done using MBean like that, but i don't know if it's the best way to do it:

```
MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName myApp= new ObjectName("jboss.as:deployment=myApp.war");
String deploymentStatus = server.getAttribute(myApp, "status").toString();
```

Any idea about how to start and stop deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to answer my question, I share my solution, it may be helpful:
- Start deployment:

```
MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName obj= null;

try {
   obj= new ObjectName("jboss.as:deployment=my_war.war");
   server.invoke(obj, "deploy", null, null);
} catch (InstanceNotFoundException | ReflectionException | MBeanException | MalformedObjectNameException e) {
      //Log error
    }
```

- To stop deployment, use "undeploy" instead of "deploy" in invoke method.